# How to map array index to a subset index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of N length. I need to create a new array of a repeating sequence. The new array will have subeset arrays that correspond to entries in the N array like:

```
N0 = [1,0,0]
N1 = [0,1,0]
N2 = [0,0,1]
N3 = [1,0,0]
N4 = [0,1,0];
reapeat...
```

expected output:  `[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0][0,1,0][0,0,1], repeating...]`

I'm drawing a blank on how to do this my first thought is to use the modulo operator on the index of each element

```
positions = [[98,8097,709], [8,907,098], [234,543w6,098], [098,087,08089], "LOL", {cool: bro}, function(){console.log(derp);}]

positions.map((pos, idx) => {
            if(idx % 1){
              return [1,0,0];              
            }

            if(idx % 2){
            return [0,1,0];
            }

            if(idx % 3){
             return [0,0,1];
            }
          })
```

Comment: Please share the `positions` array with us!

Comment: not relevant @Luca but added you an example

Comment: stop and think what `idx % 1` would evaluate to

Comment: @charlietfl 0 what about it

Comment: Right...would never be truthy in that `if()`

Comment: There was an answer that was correct and got downvoted -3 and deleted :|

Comment: `[43,534,76,87,97,89,78,67].map(function(val, idx){ var ret = [0,0,0]; ret[idx % 3] = 1; return ret})` seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `new Array(length).fill(0)` in your `map()` then use modulo to set the `1`

```js
let positions = [
  [98, 8097, 709],
  [8, 907, 098],
  [234, '543w6', 098],
  [098, 087, 08089], "LOL", {
    cool: 'bro'
  },
  function() {
    console.log('derp');
  }
]

let res = positions.map((pos, idx) => {
  let subArr = new Array(3).fill(0)
  subArr[idx % 3] = 1
  return subArr
})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok leaving my own answer here because this has gotten off target

There was an answer posted which I copied this from. It got downvoted -3 and deleted I'm not sure who the author was

```
> [43,534,76,87,97,89,78,67,7645,6534,54,54,546,657,675,68].map(function(val, idx){ var ret = [0,0,0]; ret[idx % 3] = 1; return ret})
[ [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const subarrays = [
    [1,0,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,1],
    [1,0,0],
    [0,1,0]
];

const N = 100;

result = Array.from({length: N}).map((n,idx) => subarrays[idx%subarrays.length])
```